# Adding connectors to images

Tags: port, vector-graphics, connector

I have made a simple toolkit and canvas with HTML and CSS using EXTjs. I want to simply add connectors to the puzzle piece images in order to make a flowchart. Any suggesstions on how to go about doing this?  I have several puzzle pieces and an input box, and I want to connect them preferably with ports and lines, or just lines.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Drag and Draw Workflow Analysis Diagrams</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\littleemi\Downloads\ext-4.1.0-commercial\extjs-4.1.0\ext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\littleemi\Downloads\ext-4.1.0-commercial\extjs-4.1.0\adapter\ext\ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\littleemi\Downloads\ext-4.1.0-commercial\extjs-4.1.0\ext-all-debug.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\littleemi\Downloads\ext-4.1.0-commercial\extjs-4.1.0\resources\css\ext-all.css" />
<style type="text/css">
#headings{
font-family:Arial;
color: black;
font-size: 18px;

}
body  {
padding: 10px;

}


.availableWidgets {
width:                 250px;
border-style:          solid;
border-width:          10px;    
padding:               10px;
height:                800px;
-moz-border-radius:    17px;
-webkit-border-radius: 17px;

}

.canvas{
width:                 1300px;
border-style:          solid;
border-width:          10px;    
padding:                10 px;
height:                 800px;
-moz-border-radius:     17px;
-webkit-border-radius:  17px;
}
.availableWidgets div {
border-style:          none;
padding:               3px;
margin:                20px;
cursor:                move;
text-align:            center;
}


.imgThumb {
border-style: none;
height:  100px;
width:   100px;
display: block;  
cursor: move;
margin-left: auto;   
margin-right: auto; 

}

.dropOK {
background-color: #99ff99 !important;
}

.dropNotOK {
border: 1px solid #FF0000 !important;
}

fieldset {
border: 3px solid #781351;
}



</style>

</head>
<body>
<table class="x-unselectable">
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<td align='center'>
<h1 id="headings">Available Widgets</h1>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<div id="widgets" class="availableWidgets">
<div><img src="blue_IP.png" class="imgThumb" title="IP Widget" alt="IP Widget"/></div>
<div><form action="ETservlet2" method="post">
<fieldset>
Enter URL: <input type="text" name="first" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</fieldset>
</form></div>
<div><img src="redPiece.png" class="imgThumb" title="IP Widget" alt="IP Widget"/></div>
<div><img src="orangePiece.png" class="imgThumb" title="IP Widget" alt="IP Widget"/>
</div>
<div><img src="maroonPiece.png" class="imgThumb" title="IP Widget" alt="IP Widget"/></div>
<div><img src="yellowPiece.png" class="imgThumb" title="IP Widget" alt="IP Widget"/></div>



</div>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
<td align='center' style="width: 200px;">
<table>
<tr>
<td align='center' style="width: 200px;">
<h1 id="headings">Workflow Area</h1>
</td>

</tr>
<tr  style="">
<td style="">
<div id="Canvas" class="availableWidgets canvas">

</div>
</td>

</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">

Ext.onReady(function() {
Ext.QuickTips.init();
// A list of method overrides
var overrides = {
//Called when mousedown for a specific amount of time
b4StartDrag : function() {
if (!this.el) {
this.el = Ext.get(this.getEl());
}
//this.el.highlight();
//Cache the original XY Coordinates of the element, we'll use this later.
this.originalXY = this.el.getXY();
},
// Called when element is dropped not anything other than a
// dropzone with the same ddgroup
onInvalidDrop : function() {
this.invalidDrop = true;
},
endDrag : function() {
if (this.invalidDrop === true) {
this.el.removeClass('dropOK');

var animCfgObj = {
easing   : 'elasticOut',
duration : 1,
scope    : this,
callback : function() {
this.el.dom.style.position = '';
}
};
this.el.moveTo(this.originalXY[0], this.originalXY[1], animCfgObj);
delete this.invalidDrop;
}

}
};

// Configure the widgets to be draggable
var widgetElements = Ext.get('widgets').select('div');
Ext.each(widgetElements.elements, function(el) {
var dd = new Ext.dd.DD(el, 'widgetsDDGroup', {
isTarget  : false
});
Ext.apply(dd, overrides);
});



//Instantiate instances of Ext.dd.DDTarget for the widgets container
var widgetsDDTarget    = new Ext.dd.DDTarget('widgets','widgetsDDGroup');


//Instantiate instnaces of DDTarget for the canvas drop target elements
var canvasDDTarget = new Ext.dd.DDTarget('Canvas', 'widgetsDDGroup');

//Ensure that the rented and repair DDTargets will participate in the trucksDDGroup
//canvasDDTarget.addToGroup('widgetsDDGroup');



});


</script>       


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jsPlumb is impressive and does exactly what you describe: http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html